# process has stopped during share image

Tags: android, image, share-intent

I want to share image in android. I examine a lot of code to do that but all codes make application stopped .the logcat error is as below:

```
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value ir.whc.news.model.ImageItem@41884b00
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1235)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1195)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:137)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1102)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:385)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2238)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3393)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
05-08 22:17:33.656 25125-25125/ir.whc.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is my code:

```
    package ir.whc.news.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import ir.whc.news.R;
import ir.whc.news.classes.CapturePhotoUtils;
import ir.whc.news.classes.Utility;
import ir.whc.news.model.ImageItem;

/**
 * Created by marzieh on 4/27/2016.
 */
public class SlideshowDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String TAG = SlideshowDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> images;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private TextView lblCount, lblTitle;
    private int selectedPosition = 0;
    private int scwidth;
    RelativeLayout buttom_toolbar;
    ImageView btnsave;
    ImageView btnshare;
    ImageView imageViewPreview;
    ImageItem image;

    static SlideshowDialogFragment newInstance() {
        SlideshowDialogFragment f = new SlideshowDialogFragment();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_slider, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        lblCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl_count);
        lblTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        buttom_toolbar = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.bottom_toolbar);
        buttom_toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnsave = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        btnshare = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnshare);
        btnshare.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(this);

        images = (ArrayList<ImageItem>) getArguments().getSerializable("images");
        selectedPosition = getArguments().getInt("position");
        scwidth = getArguments().getInt("scwidth");

        Log.e(TAG, "position: " + selectedPosition);
        Log.e(TAG, "images size: " + images.size());

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

        setCurrentItem(selectedPosition);

        return v;
    }

    private void setCurrentItem(int position) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
        displayMetaInfo(selectedPosition);
    }

    //  page change listener
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            displayMetaInfo(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };

    private void displayMetaInfo(int position) {
        lblCount.setText((position + 1) + " of " + images.size());

        ImageItem image = images.get(position);
        lblTitle.setText(image.get_description() != "null" ? image.get_description() : "");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnsave:
                ProgressDialog pdilog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pdilog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
                pdilog.show();

                savepic();
             pdilog.hide();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.pictureissaved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
            case R.id.btnshare:
                sharePic();

                break;
        }
    }
    private void sharePic()
    {


        Bitmap bitmap;
        OutputStream output;
        if (imageViewPreview.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageViewPreview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        } else {
            Drawable d = imageViewPreview.getDrawable();
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            d.draw(canvas);
        }
        // Find the SD Card path
        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        // Create a new folder AndroidBegin in SD Card
        File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Share Image Tutorial/");
        dir.mkdirs();

        // Create a name for the saved image
        File file = new File(dir, "sample_wallpaper.png");

        try {

            // Share Intent
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            // Type of file to share
            share.setType("image/jpeg");

            output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
            output.flush();
            output.close();

            // Locate the image to Share
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            // Pass the image into an Intnet
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            // Show the social share chooser list
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image Tutorial"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void savepic() {

        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (imageViewPreview.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageViewPreview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        } else {
            Drawable d = imageViewPreview.getDrawable();
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            d.draw(canvas);
        }
        CapturePhotoUtils.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitmap, image.get_id() + "", image.get_description());


    }

    //  adapter
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);

            imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);

            image = images.get(position);

            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(image.get_largimage_path() + "/" + scwidth)

                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imageViewPreview);

            container.addView(view);


            imageViewPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //  buttom_toolbar.setVisibility(buttom_toolbar.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE?View.INVISIBLE:View.VISIBLE);

                    if (buttom_toolbar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                        buttom_toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                buttom_toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }, 3000);

                    } else {
                      //  buttom_toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }




                  /*  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.savePicMessage))
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.Ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
*//*

                                    Bitmap bitmap;
                                    if (imageViewPreview.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                                        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageViewPreview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                                    } else {
                                        Drawable d = imageViewPreview.getDrawable();
                                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                                        d.draw(canvas);
                                    }
                                    CapturePhotoUtils.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitmap, image.get_id() + "", image.get_description());
*//*

                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.Cancle), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();*/
                }
            });


            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == ((View) obj);
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }
    }




}
```

what's wrong with my code?

**EDITE:**
`imageItem` class

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by marzieh on 4/9/2016.
 */
public class ImageItem {

    private int _id;
    private String _description;
    private String _thumb_path;
    private String _largimage_path;

    public ImageItem()
    {

    }

    public ImageItem(int _id,String _description,String _thumb_path,String _largimage_path)
    {
        this._id=_id;
        this._description=_description;
        this._largimage_path=_largimage_path;
        this._thumb_path=_thumb_path;

    }
    public String get_description() {
        return _description;
    }

    public void set_description(String _description) {
        this._description = _description;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String get_largimage_path() {
        return _largimage_path;
    }

    public String get_thumb_path() {
        return _thumb_path;
    }

    public void set_largimage_path(String _largimage_path) {
        this._largimage_path = _largimage_path;
    }

    public void set_thumb_path(String _thumb_path) {
        this._thumb_path = _thumb_path;
    }

    public static ImageItem fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject)
    {
        ImageItem imageItem=new ImageItem();

        try {
            imageItem._id=Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("id"));
            imageItem._largimage_path=jsonObject.getString("large_img");
            imageItem._thumb_path=jsonObject.getString("tb_img");
            imageItem._description=jsonObject.getString("description");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        // Return new object
        return imageItem;
    }
    public static ArrayList<ImageItem> fromJson(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        JSONObject imageItemJson;
        ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<ImageItem>(jsonArray.length());
        // Process each result in json array, decode and convert to subdomain object
        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                imageItemJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }

            ImageItem imageItem = ImageItem.fromJson(imageItemJson);
            if (imageItem != null) {
                imageItems.add(imageItem);
            }
        }

        return imageItems;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your problem lies with `ir.whc.news.model.ImageItem` and how it is being used.

Comment: this code work without share , so there is nothing wrong with `ImageItem`

Comment: Yes, there is. The error is `java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value ir.whc.news.model.ImageItem@41884b00`. Android is having difficulty attempting to work with your `ImageItem`, perhaps as it trying to pass it from one activity to another, or possibly as part of working with the saved instance state `Bundle`. If you choose not to pay attention to the error message, then nobody can help you.

Comment: @CommonsWare share image do not use `imageitem`. so i do not know what's the reason of this error! :(

Comment: can you share code inside class ImageItem?

Comment: @ankitaggarwal i did it as edite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implements your ImageItem class as `Serializable`.

```
public class ImageItem implements Serializable{

// Other stuff

}
```

Hope this will  help you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the issue is with sharing code. From stacktrace you can clearly see that framework complains about `ImageItem` class object:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value ir.whc.news.model.ImageItem@41884b00.
```

not knowing how to parcel it. Apparently you are passing your `ImageItem` objects as arguments thru bundle to your DialogFragment (your question lacks this invocation code), and to make this happen object must implement `Parcelable` interface. Your `ImageItem` is does not have required code so you need to add it (see [How can I make my custom objects be Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7181526/1235698) for info how to that or what tools to use to make required code generated). Alternatively you can use libraries like Parceler to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a crash because of this line

`images = (ArrayList<ImageItem>) getArguments().getSerializable("images");`

Actually your ImageItem is neither Serializable nor Parcelable and you are trying to send its objects in bundle as arguments. To avoid this, implement your ImageItem class with Parcelable interface.

```
public class ImageItem implements Parcelable{
    public static final Creator<ImageItem> CREATOR = new Creator<ImageItem>() {

        public ImageItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ImageItem(in);
        }

        public ImageItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ImageItem[size];
        }
    };

    public Contact(Parcel parcel) {
        _id = parcel.readInt();
        _description = parcel.readString();
        _thumb_path = parcel.readString();
        _largimage_path = parcel.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeInt(_id);
        parcel.writeString(_description);
        parcel.writeString(_thumb_path);
        parcel.writeString(_largimage_path);
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Now to send the arraylist of your ImageItem objects, just put

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayListExtra("images", imageItemList);
```

and to retrieve this list, you have to do ,

```
images = (ArrayList<ImageItem>) getArguments().getParcelableArrayListExtra("images");
```